# Integrate Amazon API Gateway with private on-premise server

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

I have an issue when trying to use Amazon API Gateway with my on-premise server.

I'm trying to use Amazon API Gateway to connect with my server but I don't want to make public APIs in my on-premise server. Is there any way to integrate Amazon API Gateway to my private APIs in the on-premise server

Comment: Probably through using API private-integration. You would also have to have a VPN between AWS and your on-premise network.

Comment: @Marcin thanks, I found that we can use AWS Site-to-Site VPN or AWS Direct Connect service to do it

Comment: DC is not something you can setup yourself. Its a long and expensive process.